# Run javaw.exe from batch in same process / show output

Tags: batch-file

i need to run a java-application from a batch file and see its output on my console. Sadly i do not have the possibility of using "java -jar", because the java i use can change. The path to the javaw.exe is read out of a .txt file which the user has to configurate before running the batch file.

So far i read in the path to javaw.exe from the configfile and call it using my parameters:

```
set /p javaPath=<startconfig.txt
call %javaPath% -jar pathToMyJar.jar
```

Sadly this doesn't give me the output the jar prints on its console. I also tried the start command with the /B and /wait switch but it didn't work either. I'm not good with batch since i use it very rarely so please tell me how to keep the javaw.exe running in the shells process or at least redirect the output of the javaw.exe to my shells console.

Thanks
Shmobi

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28987189/1683264

Comment: Im building a generic starter batch which puts multiple java options etc. together to run a jar file. This file is a server which can and will change its java-version. Besides that i know that it wants to be run with portable envoirements. So there i need to take the path as a userinput and call the javaw.exe from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "%javaPath%" -jar pathToMyJar.jar 2>&1 >pathToMyJar.log
```

Comment: If java isn't installed on the machine the command "java" wouldn't be found by the shell, would it? Think of a clean system without anything but windows and the server. The java is brought by a portable device. USB or an external harddrive etc. This wouldn't work anymore, would it?